# login issues to newly installed cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I installed 15 days trial cPanel & WHM 11.40 in CentOS installed amazon aws server. I could successfully logged into WHM with root's password. But I cannot log into cPanel (domain:2083) using the same username and password. Please help me to log into cPanel. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update nameserver or A record for the domain name in domain control panel,

After login into your whm panel==>create a new hosting account for the domain name,

Now you can able to access cpanel without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

WHM and Cpanel are actually 2 different parts. WHM is for server administration while with cpanel you can perform website management.

you need to use root password to login to WHM , however you can not use root password to login to cpanel. so in order to login to cpanel you have to use the password when you add a website through WHM. While creating the account through WHM it asks to set the password or you can use password generator feature. Copy that password , copy the cpanel username and use them to login to cpanel.

I hope that explains all.